# How to set autorotate in portrait mode in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

When you view the contents below, in landscape mode it's possible to auto-rotate.

So then How to automatically rotate in portrait mode?

How to setting?

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    //
    // There are 2 ways to support auto-rotation:
    //  - The OpenGL / cocos2d way
    //     - Faster, but doesn't rotate the UIKit objects
    //  - The ViewController way
    //    - A bit slower, but the UiKit objects are placed in the right place
    //

#if GAME_AUTOROTATION==kGameAutorotationNone
    //
    // EAGLView won't be autorotated.
    // Since this method should return YES in at least 1 orientation, 
    // we return YES only in the Portrait orientation
    //
    return ( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait );

#elif GAME_AUTOROTATION==kGameAutorotationCCDirector
    //
    // EAGLView will be rotated by cocos2d
    //
    // Sample: Autorotate only in landscape mode
    //
    if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ) {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation: kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    } else if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation: kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    }

    // Since this method should return YES in at least 1 orientation, 
    // we return YES only in the Portrait orientation
    return ( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait );

#elif GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
    //
    // EAGLView will be rotated by the UIViewController
    //
    // Sample: Autorotate only in landscpe mode
    //
    // return YES for the supported orientations

    return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( interfaceOrientation ) );

#else
#error Unknown value in GAME_AUTOROTATION

#endif // GAME_AUTOROTATION


    // Shold not happen
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation to only:

```
return ( interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
```

It will rotate for all orientations except portrait upside down.